# Can you automatically generate a parser for a type using type theory some how?

Tags: formal-grammars, type-theory, parsers, homotopy-type-theory

Was wondering since all the types are spelled out constructively, and the constructions can all be reflected symbolically on a computer, if you can automatically parse expressions in a type?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this answers your question, but most presentations of type theories include a grammar for types, which can be translated into a parser generator. For examples, you might look at the parsers for dependently typed languages such as Agda or Gallina (Coq).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind explaining a bit more what you mean that would be helpful. I kind of see what you're getting at but not sure if you mean parsing the type expressions found in math papers, or somehow in a programming language parsing an expression into a type, or something like that.

Comment: Google the tool Ott!

Comment: @LancePollard the latter.  It would be nice, since parsing sucks as a task

Answer (score 2):

In programming languages, we usually distinguish concrete syntax, where a program is represented as a linear list of symbols, from abstract syntax, where programs have a tree structure.

The vast majority of PL theory, including most type systems, happens after parsing, working with abstract syntax.

So, it's impossible to generate a parser simply from type rules or definitions, because there are arbitrarily many concrete syntaxes that could correspond to any abstract syntax. The choice is a purely human one.

In some languages, like Haskell, the description of a data type can be used to generate parsers and printers for types, using the `deriving` mechanism of the typeclass system. But it chooses a syntax that corresponds to the Haskell one by convention, and they could have chosen to define it any other way.